# What is the matrix for Invert filter in fabric js that works equivalent to Invert filter in svg?

Tags: svg, fabricjs

I want to convert the Invert filter in image in fabric js to svg. It should look same in both cases.
I am using : `new window.fabric.Image.filters.Invert()` - in `fabric js`. And in `svg`, I am using this:

```
< feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" result="Invert" type="matrix" values="-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0"/>
```

The output in both cases is different. It looks somewhat similar but not exactly same. 
I tried using this also:

```
new window.fabric.Image.filters.ColorMatrix({
                 matrix: [
                     -1,  0,  0,  0,  1,
                      0, -1,  0,  0,  1,
                      0,  0, -1,  0,  1,
                      0,  0,  0,  1,  0
                      ]
                 });
```

In this case, this shows completely black image in fabric js output. 
Does anyone know what is exact color matrix for Invert filter that will show same output for both the cases?

Comment: Make sure that you have no `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"` either on the filter primitive or any of its parent elements. I know that for example Inkscape sneakily sets it on the `<filter>` element when you use its filter editor UI. The SVG default is `linearRGB`, and that is also what fabric.js uses.

Comment: If you're using the filter from a CSS declaration, then the CSS filter will set the color space to sRGB, no matter what you declare in the filter itself. Double trickiness.

Comment: @ccprog I was not using color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" anywhere. But after using this, it worked perfectly. Thanks for taking out this point  :)  It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got resolved using **color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"** as shown:
< feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" in="SourceGraphic" result="Invert" type="matrix" values="-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0"/>

Answer (score 0):

This is a better inversion:

```
    <filter id="invert">
      <feComponentTransfer>
          <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
          <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
          <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>  </filter>
```

Comment: This does not change anything and gave same output as it was giving in : < feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" result="Invert" type="matrix" values="-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0"/>